# the title of my wordpress post changes with every new post

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I did a lot of wordpress sites before but this is the strangest thing that ever happened to me.

When i published the first post everything looks okay when i post another post the title and the thumbnail of the old post changes to be like the second one.

my site [feedbaks.com](http://feedbaks.com)

and that's a part of the index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="body">
    <div class="content-container">
        <?php 
        if (have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php 
        // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            the_post_thumbnail();
            } 
        ?>
        <div class="content">
        <h2 id="post-title">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
        <?php
            $cats=get_the_category();
            echo $cats[0]->cat_name;
            ?> : <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <div class="comments"><?php the_post(); comments_popup_link('0', '1', '%'); ?></div>
```

please help me

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your Loop is missing a function.](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Loop_Examples) You need `the_post()`, like so:

`<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`

I believe that addition will solve your problem.

[edit] Actually, `the_post()` isn't missing. It is just much too late in the function. You don't run that until just before the comments.

Comment: if i added the 'the_post();' the page just gets all mixed up
what do u mean by too late ?

Comment: ohh i got you i solved it by inserting the "<div class="comments"><?php the_post(); comments_popup_link('0', '1', '%'); ?></div>" just after the loop

Comment: That function sets a number of different values. Some template tags tend to not work correctly without it so it really should come at the beginning of the loop, as in the examples in the WordPress codex (follow my link). You have it at the bottom of the loop, right before the comments print. If putting it at the top is somehow scrambling your page then something is wrong somewhere else. You are adding it to the top and removing it from just before the comments, right? It should only be in the Loop once.